# How to return a PUBLISH message in the on_message callback without printing it (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt

This is my on_message callback written in an MQTT class, where I tried to return the PUBLISH message received:

```
def message(self):
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        Message = str(msg.payload)
        print("[Receiving msg] Topic:" +msg.topic+" / Message: "+Message)
        return Message
    return on_message
```

However, once `message` is called: `print(occupancy_sensor.message())` this is the output:

```
<function Mqtt.message.<locals>.on_message at 0x0000006BE71CAEA0>
```

The message is not returned as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MQTT Client callbacks do not return anything, and they are called from the client's network thread, not your code so even if they did return something it wouldn't be to anywhere you can get it.

In this case you can add a variable to the `message` object which you can update from with in the callback.